# How to reset NVRAM on iMac with bluetooth keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, imac, nvram

I have a problem with a swipe back in Safari. On my MacBook I could fix it by resetting of NVRAM. I can't find out how to do it on iMac with a Bluetooth keyboard. Do I really need a cable keyboard in order to reset it?

Comment: I've reset the NVRAM on my iMac with BT keyboard with no issue.  You have to turn on the iMac and then hold down the keys before the startup sound/logo appears.  If you still have a problem resetting it, try entering `nvram -c` to reset the NVRAM variables via the command line.  Then reboot

Answer (score 9):

This can be reset using Terminal.

1. Launch Terminal from the Utilities folder
2. Run the command:

`sudo nvram boot-args=”-p -r”`

3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Type your password
5. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again
6. Restart your computer

After a restart it should be reset.